# LEFT JOIN, INNER JOIN AND UNIONS, HOW TO ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

We have a SQL query that produces a report. We have sucussfully joined our settings table to update the integer values with the correct items, We have also used a union to display our three types of users.

We would like to take this query and order it by the e_job.objId field, however we are finding it really difficult with the multiple joins and unions.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated.

```
SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_student.Lastname AS 'Last Name', e_student.Name AS 'First Name', e_asset.objId AS 'Asset Number', e_asset.aSerialNumber AS 'Serial Number', si.sLabel AS 'Issue', srt.sLabel AS 'Repair Type', ss.sLabel As 'Status', e_job.note 'Description',FROM_UNIXTIME(e_job.jCreatedAt,'%d/%m/%y') AS 'Date Created'
                FROM e_job
                INNER JOIN e_student ON e_job.jName = e_student.username
                INNER JOIN e_asset ON e_job.jAsset = e_asset.aId
                LEFT JOIN e_settings si ON si.sKey = 'job_issue' AND si.sValue = e_job.jIssue
                LEFT JOIN e_settings srt ON srt.sKey = 'job_rep_type' AND srt.sValue = e_job.jRepairType
                LEFT JOIN e_settings ss ON ss.sKey = 'job_status' AND ss.sValue = e_job.jStatus
                WHERE jStatus = 1 && jRepairType = 2
                UNION
                SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_teachers.Lastname AS 'Last Name', e_teachers.Name AS 'First Name', e_asset.objId AS 'Asset Number', e_asset.aSerialNumber AS 'Serial Number', si.sLabel AS 'Issue', srt.sLabel AS 'Repair Type', ss.sLabel As 'Status', e_job.note 'Description',FROM_UNIXTIME(e_job.jCreatedAt,'%d/%m/%y') AS 'Date Created'
                FROM e_job
                INNER JOIN e_teachers ON e_job.jName = e_teachers.username
                INNER JOIN e_asset ON e_job.jAsset = e_asset.aId
                LEFT JOIN e_settings si ON si.sKey = 'job_issue' AND si.sValue = e_job.jIssue
                LEFT JOIN e_settings srt ON srt.sKey = 'job_rep_type' AND srt.sValue = e_job.jRepairType
                LEFT JOIN e_settings ss ON ss.sKey = 'job_status' AND ss.sValue = e_job.jStatus
                WHERE jStatus = 1 && jRepairType = 2
                UNION
                SELECT e_job.objId AS 'Job Number', e_supportStaff.Lastname AS 'Last Name', e_supportStaff.Name AS 'First Name', e_asset.objId AS 'Asset Number', e_asset.aSerialNumber AS 'Serial Number', si.sLabel AS 'Issue', srt.sLabel AS 'Repair Type', ss.sLabel As 'Status', e_job.note 'Description',FROM_UNIXTIME(e_job.jCreatedAt,'%d/%m/%y') AS 'Date Created'
                FROM e_job
                INNER JOIN e_supportStaff ON e_job.jName = e_supportStaff.username 
                INNER JOIN e_asset ON e_job.jAsset = e_asset.aId
                LEFT JOIN e_settings si ON si.sKey = 'job_issue' AND si.sValue = e_job.jIssue
                LEFT JOIN e_settings srt ON srt.sKey = 'job_rep_type' AND srt.sValue = e_job.jRepairType
                LEFT JOIN e_settings ss ON ss.sKey = 'job_status' AND ss.sValue = e_job.jStatus
                WHERE jStatus = 1 && jRepairType = 2
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an `ORDER BY` clause to the end of the query it should apply to the entire result set.  You can try adding this:

```
ORDER BY `Job Number`
```

Also, you don't need to specify aliases in union queries other than the first one.  The first set of aliases are what stick.

Comment: Thank you! We were using ' instead of backticks `